# Android App is shutting down when I send a push notification form a Ruby on Rails backend with FCM

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notification messages using the FCM gem to a android phone. I'm able to get the device token and I think I set everything up the way it should. Only when I use my ruby back-end to send a test message I get the following response:

```
{:body=>"{\"multicast_id\":7171621681139926581,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1556626239337337%e087ffcde087ffcd\"}]}", :headers=>{"content-type"=>["application/json; charset=UTF-8"], "date"=>["Tue, 30 Apr 2019 12:10:39 GMT"], "expires"=>["Tue, 30 Apr 2019 12:10:39 GMT"], "cache-control"=>["private, max-age=0"], "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"], "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"], "server"=>["GSE"], "alt-svc"=>["quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,44,43,39\""], "accept-ranges"=>["none"], "vary"=>["Accept-Encoding"], "connection"=>["close"]}, :status_code=>200, :response=>"success", :canonical_ids=>[], :not_registered_ids=>[]}
```

but on the Phone I don't get a notification.

my ruby backend looks like this:

```
fcm_client = FCM.new(server_key)

    # options = {:notification => "Test notification",:data => {:message => "This is a FCM Topic Message!"}}
    options = { "notification": {
        "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
        "body": "5 to 1"
        }
    }

    user_device_ids.each_slice(20) do |device_ids|

        response =  fcm_client.send_notification(device_ids, options)

        p response
    end
```

when the app is open it shuts down and I find this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service
>   NAME_OF_THE_APP.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "NAME_OF_THE_APP.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"

Now I'm not a Java Expert So I don't know what is wrong at this point. I'm testing it on a Huawei Phone.

Comment: Have you added `MyFirebaseMessagingService` to the AndroidManifest ? Read here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Yes , I did it like this : 

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/mikz_ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
            android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

Answer (score 11):

Already found my fault. I followed the guide on the firebase cloud messaging and in mine Androidmanifest the documentation says you need to pass this:

```
<service
  android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
</intent-filter>
```

but than it gives me a error that it can't find the class. After a little search if found that the android name was wrong:

It should have been :

```
<service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: after 1 day research, i have found this solution worked for me. Thanks but i am curious why google suggest to add `.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService` instead of `com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService`

Comment: wow thanks !, also wonder how come they suggest wrong name in docs !